# Use a reference to a compare operator or function to compare some values

Tags: rust, reference, compare, operators

Is there a way to have a reference to a compare operator or function in Rust to compare some values? So what I have in my mind would be ...

```
enum SomeEnum {
    A,
    B,
}

let some_enum = SomeEnum::A;
let a = 1;
let b = 2;

// What would be nice ...
let op = match some_enum {
    SomeEnum::A => {
        ge_operator // return greater_equal operator - how could this work?
    }
    SomeEnum::B => {
       ls_operator // return less operator - how could this work?
    }
};
    
let test = if a op b {
    'X'
} else {
    'Y'
};
```

Comment: Rust has first-class functions. First-class operators (/ infix functions) are not operators so that's not a thing. Though here it's not clear why you even want a function / operator, you could just have a boolean flag which you'd `==` with whichever operation e.g. `if wants_ge == (a >= b)` should work (`wants_ge` being defined as `some_enum == SomeEnum::A`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can return **functions** as needed in the match scope:

```rust
// What would be nice ...
let op = match some_enum {
    SomeEnum::A => {
        <u32 as PartialOrd<u32>>::ge // return greater_equal operator - how could this work?
    }
    SomeEnum::B => {
        <u32 as PartialOrd<u32>>::lt // return less operator - how could this work?
    }
};
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=149c73f1509a56f24c7a9c8b99e09179)

As @eggyal points out, rust can even infer the type:

```rust
let op = match some_enum {
    SomeEnum::A => PartialOrd::ge,
    SomeEnum::B => PartialOrd::lt,
};
```